# Как избежать изменения размера блока при добавлении border?

Tags: css, hover

Есть блок, у которого при наведении (*:hover*) появляется обводка (*border*). Проблема в том, что всё содержимое внутри начинает ездить (border начинает занимать пространство). Как этого можно избежать?

Comment: можно использовать box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавить прозрачный "border" в общие свойства

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  padding: 5px;
}
.block:hover {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**`box-sizing: border-box`** - для блока в котором происходит анимация
и никаких клоунад с невидимыми блоками, это свойство предусматривает размер border и изменяет размер блока под него, тем самым визуального изменения при добавлении border не происходит...

Comment: Не стоит отвечать просто «не делай этого», следует добавить «попробуй вместо этого сделать следующее» — предложите достойную альтернативу. Любой ответ, который направляет спрашивающего в нужное русло, является ценным. Постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. Изложите свои предложения. Возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше.

Comment: предложи лучше, если можешь, не вижу смысла в твоем сообщении.